# Is it possible to use replaceAll() function, to create a string that contains \n in its context?

Tags: java

I am trying to export a string to a text file with a condition, which is that string contains \n inside. With java function replaceAll(), it doesn't work.

The fun fact that i know you can escape it with \\n instead of \n, as creating just a string from scratch or adding strings together. I have already found this info in google, but my problem is that i want to use replaceAll() function, instead of just adding strings together.

```
String a = "This";
String b = "\\n";
String c = "works";
String d = a+b+c;
System.out.println(d);
String E = "This\nDoes not";
System.out.println(E.replaceAll("\n","\\n"));
```

The expected results would be:

```
This\nworks
This\nDoes not
```

,
but the actual output is:

```
This\nworks
ThisnDoesnot.
```

in the second line the "\" disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `replace` instead of `replaceAll` when replacing using character sequences.

[replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) is for regex replacing all occurrences.

[replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) is for character sequence replacing all occurrences.

**Example:**

```
System.out.println(E.replace("\n","\\n"));
```

**Output:**

> This\nworks
>
> This\nDoes not

These methods are confusingly named so I understand your confusion though.

Comment: Yes it works, thank you, these methods are confusing i agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

```
String a = "This";
String b = "\\n";
String c = "works";
String d = a+b+c;
System.out.println(d);
String E = "This\nDoes not";
System.out.println(E.replace("\n","\\n"));
```

Because it will not omit all tha ocurrences of .

Answer (score -2):

I have found the answer, one should use 4 /'s instead of 2. The code that works should be like this:

```
String a="This";
String b="\\n";
String c="works";
String d=a+b+c;
System.out.println(d);
String E="This\nDoes not";
System.out.println(E.replaceAll("\n","\\\\n"));
```

Please keep this answer for an easy future reference.